# wagtail No module named wagtail.contrib

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, wagtail

I did start wagtail fresh installation after I did and I want to use python instead python3

```
pip3 install wagtail
wagtail start wagtail02
cd wagtail02
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

when I try to do **python manage.py migrate** I get an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/lotfi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 120, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named wagtail.contrib
```

I don't find a solution on internet but if I do **python3 manage.py migrate** it work, is there a solution to make it working using python instead of python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `pip3 install wagtail` and `pip3 install -r requirements` you're installing packages under python3, and then trying to run it with python2.
To install under the correct version of python, try running:
`python -m pip install wagtail`
`python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `python` executable is Python 2.7, which Wagtail dropped support for in 2018.

However, setting up [a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) will allow you to repoint the `pip` and `python` aliases to any Python version of your choosing - you can then install Wagtail in that environment and invoke it with the `python` command.